# Cannot initialize a vector pointer with a known size that won't change for polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm making a snakes and ladders game with inheritance and polymorphism. The board is made of tiles which can be either Normal, Snake, or Ladder. Thus I have a class `Board` with a variable type `Tile` (an abstract class) that can be a `Snake` (child class) or `Ladder` (child class). The board can be as big as the user wants it to be, for this reason I'm using a vector pointer `Tile`.

I want to initialize such vector with a fix size given by the board's size but I get an error that says "`function Board::getBoardSize() is not a type name`" yet I find that everyone on the internet even my professor initializes vectors like this.

NOTE: `Board` is constructed inside another class (`MyGame`), specifically in the function called `start()` and in main I just create an object type `MyGame` to call the start function so everything happens.

Update: before Board didn't have all the variables setted up for its construction but now it does (had to move functions between classes and variables).

**Now the question is how do I increment the vector size with Tile pointers?  As it's been pointed out I need to increment its size in the Board constructor after  BoardSize is known, but what is the syntax for that? Is there a need for push_back(new Tile*)? or just push_back()?**

**Board.h:**

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include <vector>
#include "Tile.h"

class Board
{
    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();
        void setBoardSize();
        void setNumSnakes();
        void setNumLadders();
        void setReward();
        void setPenalty();
        int getBoardSize();
        int getNumSnakes();
        int getNumLadders();
        int getReward();
        int getPenalty();

    public:
        int boardSize;
        int numSnakes;
        int numLadders;
        int reward;
        int penalty;
        std::vector<Tile*> place;
};

#endif
```

**Board.cpp:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
#include "Snake.h"
#include "Ladder.h"

Board::Board()
{
    setBoardSize();
    setNumSnakes();
    setNumLadders();       //Now it has all it needs to construct
    setReward();
    setPenalty();

    place.reserve(getBoardSize());  // <------------ I think is something like this.
    for(int i = 0; i < getBoardSize(); i++)
        place.push_back();


    //initialize random seed to randomize snakes and ladders.
    srand(time(NULL));

    int index = rand() % getBoardSize() + 1;

    // All tiles are set to 'N' when the array of Tiles is created.

    //Creates (numSnakes value) Snake objets inside the vector Tile pointer in random indexes.
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumSnakes(); i++)
    {
        /*
            Makes sure it only replaces tiles when:
            - with type = 'N'
            - there is no 'S' tiles before tile 4.
            - there is no 'S' (penlaty value) tiles before the end.
        */
        while (index < getPenalty() || index > (getBoardSize() - getPenalty()) || place[index]->getType() != 'N')
            index = rand() % boardSize + 1;

        place[index] = new Snake(getPenalty());
    }

    index = rand() % getBoardSize() + 1;

    //Creates (numLadders value) Ladder objets inside the vector Tile pointer in random indexes.
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumLadders(); i++)
    {
        /*
            Makes sure it only replaces tiles when:
                - with type = 'N'.
                - there is no 'L' tiles before tile 4.
                - there is no 'L' (reward value) tiles before the end.
        */
        while (index < getReward() || index > (getBoardSize() - getReward()) || place[index]->getType() != 'N')
            index = rand() % boardSize + 1;

        place[index] = new Ladder(getReward());
    }
}

Board::~Board()
{

}

void Board::setBoardSize()
{
    int bz;

    std::cout << "Board size: ";
    std::cin >> bz;
    while (bz < 6);
    {
        std::cout << "Board size cannot be less than 6 " << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Board size: ";
        std::cin >> bz;
    }

    boardSize = bz;
}

void Board::setNumSnakes()
{
    int numS;

    std::cout << "Number of Snake tiles: ";
    std::cin >> numS;

    if(numS >= 0)
        numSnakes = numS;
    else
        numSnakes = -numS;
}

void Board::setNumLadders()
{
    int numL;

    std::cout << "Number of ladder tiles: ";
    std::cin >> numL;

    if(numL >= 0)
        numLadders = numL;
    else
        numLadders = -numL;
}

void Board::setReward()
{
    int rew;

    std::cout << "Reward (Ladder's consequence): ";
    std::cin >> rew;
    while (rew == 0);
    {
        std::cout << "The reward cannot be zero." << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Reward (Ladder's consequence): ";
        std::cin >> rew;
    }

    if(rew > 0)
        reward =  rew;
    else
        reward  = (rew * -1);
}

void Board::setPenalty()
{
    int pen;

    std::cout << "Penalty (Snake's consequence): ";
    std::cin >> pen;
    while (pen == 0);
    {
        std::cout << "The penalty cannot be zero." << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Penalty (Snake's consequence): ";
        std::cin >> pen;
    }

    if(pen < 0)
        penalty =  pen;
    else 
        penalty  = (penalty * -1);


}

int Board::getBoardSize()
{
    return boardSize;
}

int Board::getNumSnakes()
{
    return numSnakes;
}

int Board::getNumLadders()
{
    return numSnakes;
}

int Board::getReward()
{
    return reward;
}

int Board::getPenalty()
{
    return penalty;
}
```

**MyGame.h:**

```
#ifndef MYGAME_H
#define MYGAME_H

class MyGame
{

    protected:
        int numPlayers;
        int maxTurns;

    public:
        MyGame();
        ~MyGame();
        void start();
        void setNumPlayers(int);
        void setMaxTurns(int);
        int getNumPlayers();
        int getMaxTurns();
};

#endif
```

**MyGame.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyGame.h"
#include "Board.h"

MyGame::MyGame()
{

}

MyGame::~MyGame()
{

}

void MyGame::start()
{
    /*
    std::cout << "Number of player: ";
    std::cin >> numPlayers;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Maximum number of turns: ";
    std::cin >> maxTurns;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int r = setReward();
    int p = setPenalty();
    */
    numPlayers = 2;
    maxTurns = 20;

    Board brd();

    //Prints Tile's type (debugging)
    for(int i = 0; i < brd.getBoardSize(); i++)
        std::cout << i + 1 << brd.place[i]->getType() << std::endl;


}

void MyGame::setNumPlayers(int numP)
{
    if(numP > 1)
        numPlayers = numP;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The number of players isn't enough to start." << std::endl;
        numPlayers = 0;
    }

}

void MyGame::setMaxTurns(int max)
{
    if(max > 0)
        maxTurns = max;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The Limit  of turns has to be higger than 0" << std::endl;
        maxTurns = 0;
    }
}

int MyGame::getNumPlayers()
{
    return numPlayers;
}

int MyGame::getMaxTurns()
{
    return maxTurns;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyGame.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyGame snakes;

    snakes.start();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You have fooled the compiler and it's declaring a function. Use `std::vector<Tile*> place {getBoardSize()};`

Comment: You have to do that in constructor once board size is known.

Answer (score 2):

So there seem to be two mistakes, the first is just technical. The way to write the code you are trying to write is to create the board in your constructor initaliser list, like this

```
Board::Board(int rwrd, int pnlty) : place (getBoardSize())
{
    ...
}
```

But the second problem seems more serious. I don't see anything in your code that indicate that you know what the board size is when you create the Board object. In the code you've posted the board size is only known after you call the setBoardSize method, which never happens as far as I can see.

You should probably make the board size a parameter to your constructor.

Comment: Now that I have made the changes, could you help me to knwo what's the way to add more pointers to the vector. I have used dynamic memory but only the old way so vector syntax is unknown for me.

Comment: The simplest way to add values to a vector is to use `push_back` with the value you want to add. For example `place.push_back(new Ladder(reward));`.

Comment: Thx bro and also thx for letting me know about the major flaw that my code had